# Joined tables and now field calculator is greyed out using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, field-calculator, attribute-table, attribute-joins

In ArcMap 10.2, I accidentally calculated the wrong field outside of an edit session, so there was no way to reverse my action. I restored a previous version (shadow copy) and joined the tables together using the ObjectID. However, the field calculator was greyed out when I tried to restore that field's data.

Why and how do I fix it?

[Fundamentals of Field Calculations](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//005s00000025000000) have a section for troubleshooting why these buttons are greyed out, but these do not fix the problem.

Comment: Were you editing and joining feature class and/or tables?  Where was whatever you edited/joined stored?  What were the precise and detailed steps that you performed to see this situation?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem was that both the current working copy and the shadow copy tables were named the same. The join went fine but the field calculator and geometry were greyed out.

To fix this, I simply renamed the backup table name to something different. I was able to field calculate and essentially restore the data.

I did not find this resolution documented anywhere.

Comment: Well, the easy answer is that since the tables and fields are exactly the same, the code doesn't know if you want 'table(1).Field' or 'table(2).Field' I don't think it should rename the tables at random because you might mess up a process later on thinking you were working on one and not the other. I think the best answer is for ArcMAP to alert the user when both tables are named the same and ask for a potential rename or note that the fields can't be edited.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this but without the tables being named the same.  The fix was simple though unintuitive; i closed the attribute window that was open during the join (but which did update to show the join), then i reopened the attribute window and the field calculator was no longer greyed out.

Answer (score -1):

I found that after you make the join, you have to export the data as a new shapefile and it will be editable.